# YouTube-Player-iOS-Helper in Swift not working but no error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, youtube

I am using this library: https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper

- I have imported the YTPlayerView.h, YTPlayerView.m & YTPlayerView-iframe-player.html into my project.
- I made sure that the HTML file is in my Copy Bundle Resources.
- I have included the .h in my Bridging header.
- I added a UIView, gave it the YTPlayerView class and added the outlet to my ViewController.

And I am still getting just a blank UIView with no YouTube player when I run my project. No errors at all.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var ytPlayer: YTPlayerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ytPlayer.loadVideoById("8PQQZ_nwk6s", startSeconds: 0.0, suggestedQuality: .Auto)
    }
}
```

I have checked similar questions on Stack Overflow and have been unable to figure out the problem so far. Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out the problem!

First, I changed:

```
ytPlayer.loadVideoById("8PQQZ_nwk6s", startSeconds: 0.0, suggestedQuality: .Auto)
```

TO:

```
ytPlayer.loadVideoWithId("8PQQZ_nwk6s")
```

And that got me this error (which means the HTML file is not being found):

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=258 "The file name is invalid."
```

Then, I removed YTPlayerView-iframe-player.html from my project, moved it into a folder named "Assets" and then included that folder into my project and it works now.

Comment: Adding an additional comment to this answer. Make sure you include "Assets.bundle" in your project, not just the Assets folder contained in the bundle.